# How to add quick search capability to unordered list?

Tags: javascript

Before we start I want to say that I had went through a similar question on stackoverflow and I used the answer and the code is going beyond the keyword to be searched for (the `<li>` list) and the focus is also not going to the searched keyword, hence I asked this question.

I have an un-ordered list in html. 
Code

```
<nav class="float-nav closed">
  <ul id="foo"></ul> 
  <a class="toggle" href="#" style="text-decoration: none;">+</a>
</nav>
```

I am populating data using javascript.
Code:

```
var options = [
    set0 = ['Wayne Rooney', 'Frank Lampard', 'Steven Gerrard', 'Harry Kane', 'Theo Walcott', 'James Vardy', 'Raheem Sterling'],
    set1 = ['http://example.com', 'http://example.com',
            'http://example.com', 'http://example.com', 'http://example.com', 'http://example.com', 'http://example.com']];

function makeUL(array) {
    var list = document.createElement('ul');

    for (var i = 0; i < array[0].length; i++) {
        // Create the list item:
        console.log(array.length);
        var item = document.createElement('li');

        var a = document.createElement('a');
        var span = document.createElement('span');
        var linkText = document.createTextNode(array[0][i]);
        span.appendChild(linkText);
        a.target = "_blank";
        a.href = array[1][i];

        a.appendChild(span);
        item.appendChild(a);
        list.appendChild(item);
    }
    return list;
}
document.getElementById('foo').appendChild(makeUL(options));
```

And here is my code to search a keyword in the list that I populated.

```
var ul_parent = document.getElementById('foo');
var span_elements = ul_parent.getElementsByTagName("span"); 
var a_elements = ul_parent.getElementsByTagName("a");
var search_term = "Frank";
for (var i = 0, len = span_elements.length; i < len; i++) {
    var lName = span_elements[i].innerHTML.replace(/\w+\s(\w+)$/, function (_, $1) {
        return $1;
    });
    if (search_term.toLowerCase() == lName.toLowerCase()) {
        console.log('found match');
        a_elements[i].focus();
        return false;
    } else {
        console.log('not found');
    }
}
```

In the above code there is a for loop, the control is not going inside it.
Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4u37egeb/5/) for my code.

Comment: 'It's not working' is not very diagnostic. Please expand on your question with some expected behaviors. 

Note that you might have better results using data- attributes to make your search target something you don't need to parse back out of the inner html of your created elements...

Comment: You need to break out of the loop when you find a match. Otherwise you'll just go to the next span and log not found.

Comment: looks like he'd still focus the right element and log having found it, though.

Comment: @Barmar: I added the necessary code even though I had the log, but still not getting the o/p.

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: @Barmar I want to see only the searched keyword when I click on the + button, in my code 'Frank' is the keyword.

Comment: Then run the search code in the click handler. And make it use `hide()` and `show()` depending on whether the element matches the search term.

Comment: @Barmar I was able to set the focus, also found the error in my code, I am matching the keyword instead of searching it in the list.

Answer (score 1):

Would this work for you:

```
<html>
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    document.getElementById("searchbox").oninput = function () {
        var searchterm = document.getElementById("searchbox").value;
        var list_items = document.querySelectorAll("li");
        for (var i = 0; i < list_items.length; i++) {
            var li = list_items[i];
            if (li.textContent.search(searchterm) == -1) {
                li.style.visibility = "hidden";
            } else {
                li.style.visibility = "visible";
            }
        }
    };
});
</script>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="searchbox" placeholder="type here...">
    <ul>
        <li>cat</li>
        <li>dog</li>
        <li>mouse</li>
        <li>tree</li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's searching from all the <li> tags, not complaining, I will modify it.
+1^10m